# Error in Xamarin Studio when opening a VS2012 project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a solution that I have been writing in VS2012, which is comprised of 4 projects. I have done this in the past and everything has worked fine when opening them and using the, in Xamarin, but this time I receive multiple problems and I'm not sure why. At the moment, I am completely stumped and have spent most of the day looking at this. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be exceptionally grateful!

I reference two dll files in all the projects within the solution. When opening in Xamarin, I get warnings as per below:

Warning: Assembly '..............\vSphere-API-Builder\Vim25Service2012.dll' not found. Make sure that the assembly exists in disk. If the reference is required to build the project you may get compilation errors. (advantage.vmware.eventsmanager)

The references are absolutely fine under visual studio. As such, because of the missing reference (there are two in total) I cannot build the projects since there are errors due to namespace resolution.

The funny ......\ bit in the message is also shown in the solution tree for the missing files under references.

I have tried deleting the references and then re-adding them , but when I select and delete them I receive the following error:

An error has occurred. Save failed. Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: s, with the following dump..

> System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   s   at System.IO.StringReader..ctor (System.String s) [0x00031] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.12/_build/mono-2.10.12.git/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StringReader.cs:53
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StringReader:.ctor
>   (string)   at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String
>   xmlFragment, XmlNodeType fragType, System.Xml.XmlParserContext
>   context) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String xmlFragment, XmlNodeType
>   fragType, System.Xml.XmlParserContext context) [0x00006] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.12/_build/mono-2.10.12.git/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextReader2.cs:132
>   at System.Xml.XmlElement.set_InnerXml (System.String value) [0x0006f]
>   in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.12/_build/mono-2.10.12.git/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlElement.cs:156
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildProperty.set_Value
>   (System.String value) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MSBuildProject.cs:437
>   at
>   MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectHandler.SetIfPresentOrNotDefaultValue
>   (MSBuildPropertySet propGroup, System.String name, System.String
>   value, System.String defaultValue) [0x0000e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectHandler.cs:1158
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectHandler.SaveItem
>   (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00c1c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectHandler.cs:1115
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildHandler.Save
>   (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x0007e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MSBuildHandler.cs:128
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem.OnSave (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/SolutionEntityItem.cs:306
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject.OnSave (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor) [0x00027] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProject.cs:726
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.Save
>   (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem
>   entry) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectService.cs:647
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Autotools.MakefileProjectServiceExtension.Save
>   (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem
>   entry) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Autotools/MakefileProjectServiceExtension.cs:101
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.CompiledAssemblyExtension.Save
>   (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem
>   item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/CompiledAssemblyProject.cs:231
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectServiceExtension.cs:67
>   at MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem.Save (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor) [0x0002b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/SolutionEntityItem.cs:253
>   at MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.Save
>   (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem entry) [0x0004b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-evolve_fixed/a8bf58d3/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/ProjectOperations.cs:362